# Lattice of chains of a poset?

Tags: order-theory, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

Let $(P,\le)$ be a poset, and $C$ be its set of (saturated, if needed) chains, i.e., set of totally ordered subsets of $(P,\le).$ Is there any canonical ordering and meet, join operations on $C$ that makes it into a lattice? Can we make this into a distributive lattice?

I was thinking about this question for few hours, but couldn't construct anything satisfactory. Therefore thought to ask the opinion of people familiar with order theory. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "canonical ordering" ? Like what a canonical (lattice) ordering on a finite set ?

Comment: @AlexL: By canonical, I mean a  particular choice of an ordering among all possible orderings more natural and intuitive than others. First paragraph of the top answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19644/what-is-the-definition-of-canonical) represents the my use of "canonical."

Comment: Well basically $C$ is a set and there is a (non canonical) bijection between $C$ and its cardinal, which is a total ordered set (as an ordinal), so a lattice

Comment: A complete lattice would have a top element. What would be the top element of the "lattice of chains" of a poset which is not totally ordered? By the way, how do you define the "lattice of chains" for a **finite** poset? (If you haven't done that, that trying to do it for an **uncountable** poset seems kind of like trying to run before you can walk.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intersection will make C a
meet semilattice.
If C is lower complete, then intersection
will make C is a complete meet semilattice.
There is, in general, no join.
The chains of 0 < a,b are
empty set, {0}, {a}, {b}, {0,a}, {0,b}.
As {{0,a}, {0,b}} has no upper bound, it has no join.
Trivally, linear orders are lattices and
complete linear orders are complete lattices.